# Kafka Streams Punctuator check time sent of an entry in StateStore

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I've imlemented my own `Transformer`, where I'm accumulating events in my `StateStore` (into the internal changelog kafka topic), and once it accumulates X events, I emmit one accumulated event down the stream.

Everything is perfect, but I don't want accumulated events to be stuck in the pipe if there are no new events are posted for a while.

That's why I decided to use Punctuator:

```
@Override
public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.kvStore = (KeyValueStore<Patient, Long>) this.context.getStateStore(stateStore);
    this.context.schedule(Duration.ofMinutes(180), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, (timestamp) -> {
      KeyValueIterator<Event, Long> iter = kvStore.all();
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
        KeyValue<Event, Long> entry = iter.next();
        ...
      }
      iter.close();
      context.commit();
    });

}
```

The problem is that the entries in the `StateStore` do not contain time sent information. Is there a way to access that? Do I need to implement my own custom `StateStore` in order to make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: as an option, you could put key-value into state store where value has timestamp field (which will be populated either at event time, or when you put data at state store)

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi yes that's certainly a good option, but I know that Kafka already has that information, I just don't know how to retrieve it.

Comment: Atm, you would need to add the information manually. Note, that we are currently working on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-258%3A+Allow+to+Store+Record+Timestamps+in+RocksDB and this will provide exactly what you want.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Yep, I ended up having Pair value:
`KeyValueStore<Event, Entry<Long, ZonedDateTime>>` for now. Will switch as soon as a stable release includes KIP-258

thank you. Will post an answer to this question once that happens